# Obtaining widget UI references

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

After doing some coding for widgets, I've been wondering if I'm correct in assuming that the only way you can modify UI elements is through `RemoteViews` and there is no way to obtain a reference to any elements on the widget (TextView, ImageView, etc.).  Or is there a way to store references to these specific elements of my layout?  Perhaps through intents or constructors?  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

> After doing some coding for widgets

Given the context of the rest of your question, I am interpreting "widgets" to mean "app widgets".

> I've been wondering if I'm correct in assuming that the only way you can modify UI elements is through RemoteViews

Generally speaking, yes.

> there is no way to obtain a reference to any elements on the widget (TextView, ImageView, etc.)

Correct. The app widgets are rendered by the home screen, and so the home screen's process is the one that has the `View` objects, not yours. The exception would be if you write your own home screen.